# Is there any way that I can validate whether or not a Facebook page is able to post to, or is a member of, a group through the graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to allow a user to choose which page they'd like to post to a specified group from. Unfortunately, `/{page-id}/groups` doesn't exist. I can't select from `/{group-id}/opted_in_members` due to the fact that there are no filters, and it's not reasonable to iterate through every single page of results searching for the pageId in question when there are potentially millions of members. There doesn't seem to be a way to fetch `Group <=link=> Page` relationships from the API.

It seems the only way to get feedback on this from the API is to attempt to post from the page, which then gives you an OAuth if the page is not linked to the group.

Does anybody have any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

You need to get the `accessToken` of the page in question using `/me/accounts`. You then need to call `/{user-id}/groups` using the page's `accessToken`. This will give you the groups that the page is a member of.